# macOS Client 10.12.x / Enable SMB Sharing only on one interface

Tags: macos, mac, samba

I need to enable SMB `File Sharing` on a macOS client only on one interface. By default the GUI enables it on all interfaces.

Using a global section in `/etc/smb.conf` is not respected.

```
[global]
    interfaces = eth0 lo
    bind interfaces only = yes
```

The OS standard `smbd` appears to only use the `com.apple.smb.server.plist` for its configuration but I can find any docs on how an interface list would be defined in it (or if that is even supported...)

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist
```

Without resorting to a *standard* smbd, any way to do this?